# Create DataTable from SQL Connection String in Web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I need to display data from a table in my SQL Server DB on a webpage. I've got a connection string in my Web.config file like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Products.ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=...."
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

In my aspx I've got a GridView with a ObjectDataSource to display the data. 
In the code behind I created a method in terms of a List to return the values from my database table. However, now I was told that the users need to be able to filter the data so I created a textbox and a button to enable this but then realised in this case it would be better to have a DataTable than a List. I've always used Lists for those kind of projects though so I'm not sure how to achieve the same in a DataTable. 
Here is what the code for my List looks like:

```
 public class Products
{

    public string Name { get; set;} 
    public int Price { get; set; }



    public List<Products> DataTable()
    {
        List<Products> myList = new List<Products>();

        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Products_Table] ";
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Products_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; //Read connection string from config file


        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
            {

                con.Open(); //Open connection
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Products t = new Products();
                        t.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                        t.Price = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Price"]);


                        myList.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return myList;

    }
}
```

So would be great if somebody could get me on the right track for replacing the list with a DataTable in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code behind you need to do something like this:

```
public static class ProductsDataSource
 {
public static DataTable LoadProducts()
 {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Products_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products_Table", conn))
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(data);
        return data;
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're using ObjectData Source make sure you're defining the SelectMethod and Typename correctly in order to return the data. Something like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
TypeName="ProductsDataSource"
SelectMethod="LoadProducts" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like -

```
GridView1.DataSource = DataTable();
```

Comment: you could always implement filter,sorting or paging.

Comment: Google it. There are a lot of examples

Answer (score 0):

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString);
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Table];";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

I dont know of that`s what you are looking for, but this is how you bind a GridView with a DataTable.